# Reading from one db table and storing it in 2 object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, web

**These are the two Methods am having a problem with**

I want to return both object of csVehicle and csDistributor 
as you my code below only returns csVehicle

please help

```
public List<csVehicle> get_All_Vehicles()
{            
    var objv = new List<csVehicle>(); 
    IDataReader dr = null;
    var objdal = new csDAL();
    dr = objdal.executespreturndr("sp_Get_All_Distributor");
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var d = new csDistributor();     // I put this here so that I can use the propDistrbutorId
        var v = new csVehicle();
        populate_Data(dr, d,v);
        objv.Add(v);                    //It only adds object of csVehicles and csDistributor is not added
    }
    return objv;                        // csDistributor is not returned
}
```

the populate_Date methods adds data to the two objects csDistributor and csVehicle

```
private void populate_Data(IDataReader dr, csDistributor d, csVehicle v)
{
    v._vehicleRegNo = dr["VehicleRegNo"].ToString();
    d.propDistrbutorId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DistrbutorId"]);                      
}
```

Comment: Try puting a break point in the populate_data method and see what the value of dr["DistributorId"] is.

Comment: You are creating a collection of only csVehicle not csDistributor (example List<csVehicle>() ).What properties do you have in your csVehicle  class ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
public List<object> get_All_Vehicles()
{            
    var objv = new List<object>(); 
    IDataReader dr = null;
    var objdal = new csDAL();
    dr = objdal.executespreturndr("sp_Get_All_Distributor");
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var d = new csDistributor();
        var v = new csVehicle();
        populate_Data(dr, d,v);
        objv.Add(v);                
        objv.Add(d);    
    }
    return objv;                        
}
```

A more sophisticated solution would be to define a parent class from which both csDistributor and csVehicle inherit, and then return a `List<>` of that specific type.

Or use an `ArrayList`, which is just an untyped collection of objects.

**Edit:** I'm sort of having to guess how your code is being used elsewhere, but try this:

```
public void get_All_Vehicles(out csVehicle vehicle, out csDistributor distributor)
{            
    vehicle = new List<csVehicle>(); 
    distributor = new List<csDistributor>();
    IDataReader dr = null;
    var objdal = new csDAL();
    dr = objdal.executespreturndr("sp_Get_All_Distributor");
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var d = new csDistributor();
        var v = new csVehicle();
        populate_Data(dr, d,v);
        vehicle.Add(v);                
        distributor.Add(d);    
    }
}
```

Comment: It has a runtime error because "objv.Add(v)" and objv.add(d). It adds them on Index 0,1 and that cause error since they ar no of equal size. @MusiGenesis